# PyQt5 show a closed subwindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, mdi

I'm trying to show a subwindow after It was closed by the X button. I made the graphic with Qt designer.

**main.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(402, 332)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 401, 291))
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.subwindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.subwindow.setObjectName("subwindow")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.subwindow)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 402, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuStart = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuStart.setObjectName("menuStart")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpenSubWin = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpenSubWin.setObjectName("actionOpenSubWin")
        self.menuStart.addAction(self.actionOpenSubWin)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuStart.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.subwindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Subventana"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.menuStart.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.actionOpenSubWin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OpenSubWin"))
```

And the code for creating the app.

**gestor.py**

```py
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from resources.main import *

class myMainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myMainClass, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
        #conection
        self.ui.actionOpenSubWin.triggered.connect(self.showSubWin)

    def showSubWin(self):
        self.ui.subwindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('start')
    app = QApplication([])
    myapp = myMainClass()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So, It open well, but if Y close the subwindow an the call the `self.ui.subwindow.show()` It crashes.

I'v aso tried to put the subwindow in a variable an then create again, It doesn't crash but a open a window without the button that was inside.

```py
class myMainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myMainClass, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        self.sw=QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        self.sw.setWidget(self.ui.subwindow)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.sw)
        #conection
        self.ui.actionOpenSubWin.triggered.connect(self.showSubWin)

    def showSubWin(self):
        self.sw.setWidget(self.ui.subwindow)
        self.sw.show()
```

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding the way that Pyqt manage that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt (with the variable sw) is the correct way to go. Although you can simplify your 3 lines, just by keeping the returned value of addSubWindow:

```
self.sw = self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
```

Then you need to disable the "delete on close" flag for sw:

```
self.sw.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, False)
```

The [doc of QWidget.close](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.close) mentions this flag:

> First it sends the widget a PySide.QtGui.QCloseEvent. The widget is **hidden** if it accepts the close event. If the widget has the Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose flag, the widget is also deleted.

The subtle point is to set this flag on the `self.sw` (a QMdiSubWindow), not on `self.ui.subwindow` (the widget within, which gets the close event too late, after `self.sw` has been deleted).

Comment: Thank for answering.
I've Wrote as you said

`self.sw = self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
 self.sw.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, False)
`
But the second time I open the window, is empty. There should apear a button. but there's nothing.

Comment: hmm, I don't seem to have this issue here (if you indeed mean the PushButton is hidden or detroyed). The PushButton is still within the subWindow in my test. I doubled checked, my only modif to your first code is those 2 lines 16-17 in gestor.py, (and the `from resources.main import *` that I had to change to `from main import *`).

Comment: The form as opened  
[opened form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpTnO.jpg)  

Closed the subwindow an reopened, the button is not there
[reopened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLd49.png)

Comment: I run it on linux, using either PyQt5 or PySide2, and don't have your issue. Maybe try pip upgrade PyQt5 if you can?

Comment: You could also try to see if the pushbutton is hidden or has been destroyed?

Comment: Changed 
    `def showSubWin(self):
        self.sw.setWidget(self.ui.subwindow)
        print(str(self.ui.pushButton.isHidden()))
        self.ui.pushButton.show()
        self.sw.show()
`
But the behaviour is the same. It says in not hiden. But doesn't show it

Comment: I can't update becouse I'm using the PyQt, provided by Qgis 3.10

Comment: I don't have a py3+Qt5 installed on windows right now, but I was planning to do so next week (I'll keep you informed if I experience your same issue). If your lucky, another Windows user will step in this conversation in the meantime!